Explicit description of Hopf invariant
From the long exact sequence of a fibration, we get that $\pi_3(S^2) \cong \mathbb{Z}$. We can now define the map $H \colon \mathbb{Z} \to \pi_3(S^2)$ by sending $1$ to the class of the Hopf fibration $\eta \colon S^3 \to S^2, \; (z,w) \mapsto \frac{z}{w}$, where I view $S^2 \cong \mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$. My question is now: How does this map look explicitly? The hopf map is a generator, so $H$ is an isomorphism. By linearity, we wish to have that $k$ sends to $k \cdot [\eta]$ under $H$. What is the latter? I would believe that it is the homotopy class of the map $S^3 \to S^2$ that maps $(z,w)\mapsto \left(\frac{z}{w}\right)^k$.
If so, how does one make this rigorous using the group structure on the homotopy groups?
Edit: I‘m really asking for the map $H$, i.e. I want to know what $k \cdot [\eta]$ is, not an explicit description of the Hopf fibration $\eta$!
Edit 2: May this be some kind of Eckmann-Hilton argument?
This was also talked about in the following post: How does the Hopf map generate $\pi_3(S^2)$?
However, I couldn’t really parse it.

These really are two separate questions. The first is asking for an explicit formula for a specific map and the latter is a general property of the Hopf invariant in all dimensions. I suggest you ask one question at a time.

@Thorgott Now that I‘ve already asked the question, do I ask the questions separately again or do I simply leave it as it is? Thank you for the remark, though.

I suggest you edit this question so that it only asks one question. If you then have another question, post another question.

Done. Thank you.

Re: Edit 2: I doubt it. It is true that if $X$ is an $H$-space, then the group structure on $\pi_k X$ agrees with the one induced by the multiplication of $X$ (via an Eckmann-Hilton argument). But $S^2$ is not an $H$-space: For instance its tangent bundle is not trivializable. The group structure on $S^3$ doesn't help either: To apply Eckmann-Hilton, you would need a second (homotopy) cogroup structure on $S^3$.

In any case, you should be able to figure out some description of a representative by walking your map back over the quotient $I^3 \twoheadrightarrow I^3 / \partial I^3 \cong S^3$ and then using the explicit formula for composition on maps of the form $(I^3, \partial I^3) \to S^2$. Whether this is useful and/or enjoyable is left as an open question for the asker :)

Are you implying that my claim is incorrect? Either way, walking back over the homeomorphism of $I^3/\partial I^3 \cong S^3$ sounds really tedious, doesn’t this make it even more complicated than using the other description via the pinch map?

Rather trying to post-compose $\eta$ with some kind of map on $S^2$, where the effect is less than transparent, why not pre-compose $\eta$ with the "multiplication by $k$" map on $\pi_3(S^3)$? That map is easy to describe, by making use of the Freudenthal suspension isomorphisms $\pi_1(S^1) \to \pi_2(S^2) \to \pi_3(S^3)$. Knowing that the "multiplication by $k$" map on $\pi_1(S^1)$ is induced by the map $z \mapsto z^k$ on $S^1$, it follows that the "multiplication by $k$" map on $\pi_3(S^3)$ is induced by restriction to $S^3$ of the map $f_k : (z,w) \mapsto (z^k,w)$ defined on $\mathbb C^2$.
To add some details, by using functoriality of $\pi_3$ it follows that the map $\eta : S^3 \to S^2$ induces a homomorphism $\eta_* : \pi_3(S^3) \to \pi_3(S^2)$. This homomorphism takes the generator of $\pi_3(S^3) \approx \mathbb Z$, namely the element $[Id]$ represented by the identity map $Id : S^3 \to S^3$, to the generator $[\eta]$ of $\pi_3(S^2) \approx \mathbb Z$, represented by the composition $\eta \circ Id = \eta$, that is: $\eta_*([Id]) = [\eta]$. This homomorphism therefore also takes the element $[f_k] = k[Id]$ (represented by the map $f_k$ described in my previous paragraph) to the element $k[\eta]$, that is:
$$\eta_*([f_k]) = \eta_*(k[Id]) = k\eta_*([Id]) = k[\eta]
$$

How does this answer my question or even relate to the image of $k$ under the image of $H$, that is, $H(k) = k \cdot [\eta] = [\eta \ast \cdots \ast \eta]$, where the latter denotes the $k$-fold group operation in the homotopy group $\pi_3(S^2)$? From what I understand, you’re describing the multiplication by $k$ map explicitly in $\pi_3(S^3)$. My question here is now, however, if $f$ denotes this multiplication by $k$ map, why is $\eta \ast \cdots \ast \eta$ homotopic to $\eta \circ f$, the latter is what you were hinting at, but I don’t see how this homotopy exists from your comment.

I added another paragraph of details.

I prefer write $S^2$ as the complex projective space $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^1$, which is $\mathbb{C}^2\setminus \{0\}$ modulo $\mathbb{C}^\times$-action $\lambda(x,y)=(\lambda x,\lambda y)$.
$$
\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^1 = \frac{\mathbb{C}^2\setminus \{0\}}{\mathbb{C}^\times}.
$$
One can also think of $\mathbb{C}^2\setminus \{0\}$ as the collection of $1$-dimensional subspaces in $\mathbb{C}^2$. This is really $\mathbb{C}^1$ union $\{\infty\}$, where the injection $\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^1$ is given as
$$
z \mapsto (1,z).
$$
Then the point of infinity is $(0,1)$.
Since $\mathbb{C}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$, we can think $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^1$ as
$$
\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^1 = \frac{\mathbb{R}^4\setminus\{0\}}{\mathbb{C}^\times}.
$$
If we think of $\mathbb{R}^+$-action instead of $\mathbb{C}^\times$-action, we are quotienting out under the scalar multiplication, so we must get
$$
S^3 = \frac{\mathbb{R}^4\setminus \{0\}}{\mathbb{R}^+}.
$$
The $\mathbb{R}^+$-orbit of $(a,b,c,d)$ is represented by the point
$$
\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}},\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}},\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}},\frac{d}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}}\right)\in S^3.
$$
Now $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^1$ is quotiented out by the larger set, we have the natural surjection
$$
S^3 \to \mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^1,
$$
where $(a,b,c,d)$ is mapped to the $\mathbb{C}^\times$-orbit of $(a+bi,c+di)$. Or equivalently, one can think of the $S^1$-action on $S^3$,
$$
e^{i\theta}(a,b,c,d)=(a\cos\theta-b\sin\theta,a\sin\theta+b\cos\theta,c\cos\theta-d\sin\theta,c\sin\theta+d\cos\theta)
$$
which is just the diagonal action of $e^{i\theta}=cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ on $(a+bi,c+di)\in \mathbb{C}^2\setminus \{0\}$. Thus we see that $S^1$ is the fiber of the Hopf fibration.

I‘m sorry if my question is misleading, but I was asking for an explicit description of the $H$ map, what is $k \cdot [p]$ explicitly? Unless I‘m misunderstanding something, that doesn’t answer the question, right?

This is a nice description of the Hopf fibration, but it does not answer the question.
